# Keycloak not initializing MySQL database

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I had this working, but decided to install from scratch due to other issues.
Albeit copying my configuration as well as Java driver bundle 1:1 using `cp`, it will now no longer create the SQL schema. I tried the "manual" initialization option as well, however no SQL file was being generated.

The steps I performed to start from scratch were:

1. dropping the existing database
2. creating a new database, granting the same privileges
3. moving away the keycloak directory
4. extracting a new keycloak tarball
5. copying and replacing the keycloak configuration from the previous instance
6. copying the MySQL JDBC driver bundle from the previous instance

```
2021-08-18 13:59:15,511 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service
org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.channel.ee:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.channel.ee:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:66)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsyncServiceConfigurator$AsyncService.lambda$start$0(AsyncServiceConfigurator.java:117)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTa
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.dumpSocketInfo(UDP.java:556)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.createSockets(UDP.java:422)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.start(UDP.java:292)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:881)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:989)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.11.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:853)
2021-08-18 13:59:21,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0272: Suspending server
2021-08-18 13:59:21,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-1) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
2021-08-18 13:59:21,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
2021-08-18 13:59:21,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4)
WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2021-08-18 13:59:21,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source
[java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
2021-08-18 13:59:21,775 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https
stopped, was bound to 192.168.0.115:8443
2021-08-18 13:59:21,775 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp
stopped, was bound to 192.168.0.115:8009
2021-08-18 13:59:21,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment
keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 76ms
2021-08-18 13:59:21,774 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default
stopped, was bound to 192.168.0.115:8080
2021-08-18 13:59:21,782 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.2.5.Final stopping
2021-08-18 13:59:21,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 15.0.1 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) stopped
in 96ms
```

I tried recreating this several times, but I cannot figure out what is different from the first time I installed it. I am using the Standalone HA operation mode.

Would appreciate any input.

I think to have pasted the relevant bits, but in case it is of any help, here's the server.log as a file: http://hugz.io/ryxgd9/server.log

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by starting the instance with the default standalone-ha.xml, only including the driver and datasource sections, and only afterwards copying in the other modified sections.